# How do I include MySql.Data.dll when deploying C# console App

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, dll

I am just rewriting the question here:

I am building a console app that uses MySql connector. So I add reference to the dll in the project. When I compile the solution, I get an exe that runs fine on my own machine, but when I copy the exe to another machine, it doesn't work, because it can't find the Mysql dll. I have tried to copy the dll into the same folder as the exe on the other machine but no luck.

I also tried putting the dll in the same folder on same machines, but that didn't work either.

How do I deploy the dll correctly with my exe?

Comment: Does the MySQL DLL contain native code? Did you at any point have to pick between a 64-bit version or a 32-bit version? Does the code work on your machine?

Comment: MySql only have a 32 bit connector dll but it works on 64 bit deployment. The code works fine on my own (64 bit PC), no matter from where I run the exe.

Comment: If it's a native DLL, I wouldn't expect it to work from an explicitly-64-bit assembly. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

I had some different errors in the setup. It has to be the correct assembly dll (6.3.0) to work and also I needed to create the user@server and grant him privileges. But the dll is accessible when it's in the same folder as the exe.